# lexer skips a token

Tags: antlr3, lexer

I am trying to do basic ANTLR-based scanning. I have a problem with a lexer not matching wanted tokens.

```
lexer grammar DefaultLexer;

ALPHANUM    :   (LETTER | DIGIT)+;
ACRONYM     :   LETTER '.' (LETTER '.')+;
HOST        :   ALPHANUM (('.' | '-') ALPHANUM)+;

fragment
LETTER  :   UNICODE_CLASS_LL | UNICODE_CLASS_LM | UNICODE_CLASS_LO | UNICODE_CLASS_LT | UNICODE_CLASS_LU;

fragment
DIGIT   :   UNICODE_CLASS_ND | UNICODE_CLASS_NL;
```

For the grammar above, `hello. world` string given as an input results in `world` only. Whereas I would expect to get both `hello` and `world`. What am I missing? Thanks.

ADDED:

Ok, I learned that input `hello. world` matches more characters using rule HOST than ALPHANUM, therefore lexer will choose to use it. Then, when it fails to match input to the HOST rule, it does not "look back" to , because that's how lexer works.

How I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a foreword, ANTLR 4 would not behave in a strange manner here. Both ANTLR 3 and ANTLR 4 *should* be matching `ALPHANUM`, then giving 2 syntax errors, then matching another `ALPHANUM`, and I can state with confidence that ANTLR 4 *will* behave that way.

- It looks like your `HOST` rule might be better suited to be `host`, a parser rule.
- You need to make sure and provide a lexer rule that can match `.` (either together or as two separate tokens).

Comment: Ok, I will give antlr4 a try.

Comment: I can't get antlr4 to generate C#. After I modified a project according to https://github.com/sharwell/antlr4cs, I get `Error 16 Unknown build error: Error: Could not find or load main class Studio` during the build. And if I try to run antlr4-csharp-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT-complete.jar manually from the command line, it generates java classes.

Comment: Ok, I was able to generate C# from the command line by using exact the same parameters msbuild task would use. Still no idea why it does not work at build time.